# Check code in loop doesn't working properly

Tags: arrays, vb.net

I made a code capable of downloading values in a web page and it works well. Since the values are taken in real time, that is, data download is performed only when there are actually changes, I need if a certain value is changed.
I then created a code that allows me to get check from all elements of the array with the updated values and the array with the old values.
The code actually detects when a given result has changed, but for some strange reason, the message appears to infinity, as if it were stuck in a foor that takes no arguments, and this is very strange.

```
For Each abc As Country_Data In lista
                For Each xyz As Country_Data In vecchia_lista
                    If abc.casa = xyz.casa And abc.ospite = xyz.ospite Then
                        If abc.Result <> xyz.Result Then
                            MsgBox(abc.casa & " - " & abc.ospite & " -- " & abc.Result)
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    End If
                Next
            Next
```

**Variable definition**

```
Dim lista As New List(Of Country_Data)
    Dim vecchia_lista As New List(Of Country_Data)
    Private Structure Country_Data
        Dim casa As String
        Dim ospite As String
        Dim Result As String
    End Structure
```

how to fix this?

Comment: "the message appears to infinity, as if it were stuck in a foor that takes no arguments" -- can you please clarify this?

Comment: In the sense that the message should appear only once, which indicates precisely if the result "x" is changed or not. In this case it does endlessly, like saying for (;;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments, I'm gathering that you only ever want to see one message box, when it finds the first case where a result has changed (even though there could be others after that).

The `Exit For` you're using only exits from the inner `For` loop, and thus the outer `For` loop continues to loop, which is probably what you're observing.

You can do something like this:

```
Dim keepLooping As Boolean = True

For Each abc As Country_Data In lista
    For Each xyz As Country_Data In vecchia_lista
        If abc.casa = xyz.casa And abc.ospite = xyz.ospite Then
            If abc.Result <> xyz.Result Then
                MsgBox(abc.casa & " - " & abc.ospite & " -- " & abc.Result)
                keepLooping = False
                Exit For
            End If
        End If
    Next

    If (Not keepLooping) Then Exit For
Next
```

That way when you want to stop looping, it will set the boolean flag and that will be observed by the outer loop, causing it to exit as well.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't understand.

Comment: It seems to be working well, even if the message reappears after a few moments. You believes that if I add "lista.clear()" immediately after printing the message would solve the situation?

Comment: The message should not reappear.  You must be doing something else that you're not showing here.

Comment: I paste my complete class here:
http://pastebin.com/2StsPdGn
please if you have a time check the code this is a big problem for me.